# Ordering records when using has_and_belongs_to_many relation in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, relationship

I am, for the first time, trying to use a HABTM relationship in my Rails application. The following image shows the models and their relations to each other:

[image: Schema]

Currently I am displaying all members within a region with the following:

```
<% @region.members.each do |member| %>
  <%= link_to member.name, member %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to sort/order the list of members by their respective level. I then would like to have the members ordered in descending alphabetical order.

So, the members_controller code is currently the default:

```
@members = Member.all
```

I can order the results into alphabetical order:

```
@members = Member.order("name DESC").all
```

but I can't figure out how to use a related model's data to order the member records. There are likely going to be three levels; Charity, Basic and Subscription. I am planning on having a block at the top of the page which only shows subscription members. The subscription members should not then be shown again on the page.

```
@subscribed_members = Member.where(:level == 1).order("name DESC").all
```

but, as you can see, I have no idea how to filter that block by level.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or maybe to a tutorial for this? I've read through the Rails guide for HABTM relationships but it only seems to cover the models.

**EDIT**

After trying the suggestion, I now have the following:

```
@members = Member.all
@subscribedmembers = Member.include(:levels)
                         .where("levels.name == 'subscriber'")
```

How do I use that method in the regions view?

```
<% @region.subscribedmembers.each do |member| %>
   <%= member.name %>
<% end %>
```

That won't work because it's looking for a related model called subscrivedmembers which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task, i recommend you to take a look at joining models with `ActiveRecord`. The methods are `include` and `joins`. Lemme demonstrate with a piece of code:

```
@subscribed_members = Member.include(:levels)
                            .where("members.url == 'test_url'")
                            .order("levels.name DESC")
```

If you check your console after this query is run, you can see the `include` makes a SQL join with the two tables. Here i am assuming `member :has_many :levels`, so you include the `:levels` table and use a prefixed column name on your `order` clause.
It is not that hard once you get the idea, so i encourage you to try these two methods on the console and check the results.

**EDIT**

Create a scope with you query code, then use it on any place. Example:

```
# On your model
scope :ultimate_level, include(:levels).where("name = 'test'").order("levels.name DESC")

# On your controller
@subscribed = Member.ultimate_level

# On your view
<% @subscribed.each do |s| %>
```

You can create different scopes too, each one that makes a single operation, and then reuse on our controllers, etc. 
Obs.: Check the syntax, i didn't test the code myself.

Comment: Thanks! I've got the filtering working - but now do you use that filter in a loop? I've updated my question with what I mean..

Comment: Hmm, I think there is a syntax error that I can't find. Also, I don't think I can call @regions.subscribed from regions views can I?